# find() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape imdb top 250 movies, but I am facing this error:

> find() takes no keyword arguments

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/')
    source.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
    movies = soup.find('tbody',class_="lister-list")
    for movie in movies:
        name = movie.find('td',class_="titleColumn").a.text
        print(name)
        break
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question**; don't just show an error and code. We need to understand what you expect to happen instead, what your understanding is of the error, and specifically what help you need from us. In order to understand the error properly, please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. [Please also try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to help yourself first, by looking in documentation and [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code.

Comment: Using [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) would be really helpful for you in diagnosing this problem once you replace your `print(e)` with `raise`.

Comment: So what is the type of `movie`? It seems like you're using the wrong method. As others have said, try debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out `find()` and `find_all()` in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find).
For your case, you can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/')
    source.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
    movies = soup.find('tbody',class_="lister-list")
    names = movies.find_all('td',class_="titleColumn")
    for name in names:
        print(name.a.text)     
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```